# How to "search and replace" many files?

Tags: command-line, files

I use the `grep` command to search for a string in many files. Is there something similar to "search and replace"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are looking for the [`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) command. For example, to replace the "dog" with "cat" in all text files in the current directory:

```
sed -i 's/dog/cat/' *.txt
```

Comment: Simple and nice.

Answer (score 1):

sed comes to mind. Example:

```
sed s/cat/dog/ <input >output
```

This searches for cat in a line and puts dog on it's place in the file input and writes to file output.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is the right tool; but, as an alternative, you can even use `ex` commands in `vim`:

```
vim -c 'args <files> | argdo %s/cat/dog/g | x'
```

where `<files>` is the list of files or patterns in which you want to make the substitution.

Comment: note argdo is not POSIX http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
for b in *.txt
do
  ex -sc '%s/OLD/NEW/g|x' "$b"
done
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `g` replace all instances in each line
4. `x` save and close